# get 5th previous date from current date through SQL except public holiday

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need a sql function which has to return 5th previous business date except saturday sunday and public holiday,

Ex: i should get last thursday (04-01-2018) if i won't have any public holiday inbetween im able to achieve that by,

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                        WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                        ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 5, GETDATE()))
```

but how to omit public holiday from this,
Can anyone help me please

Comment: Do you have the holidays stored in a table?

Comment: Create a Calendar table that contains dates and whether they are weekends, public holidays or not, etc. Each country has its own public holidays and they can change them at any time. A calendar table will make the query a LOT easier too, as you'll be able to eliminate the `CASE` entirely

Comment: @Luc yes i have them in a separate table

Comment: Once you have the calendar table you can use the [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function to return a previous value in a result set that doesn't include holidays, eg `LAG(Date,-5) OVER (ORDER BY Date) FROM Calendar Where IsWeekend=0 and IsHoliday=0 ...`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you please provide a sample

Comment: @VickyS, try my answer, hope that helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want (or you can't) create a calendar "tally" table (with columns identifying holidays and week-end days) you can try a query like following one.

sample data for holidays table

```
CREATE TABLE HOL_TAB (DAT DATETIME);
INSERT INTO HOL_TAB VALUES ('2018-01-05');
INSERT INTO HOL_TAB VALUES ('2018-01-04');
```

The query use a CTE to "create" on the fly a small tally calendar table (I used 12 as limit, but you can change it).

The last `SELECT` use a join with holiday table to exclude those days and then `ROW_NUMBER()` to extract "first" five days.

To keep query similar to the one you made I used `DATENAME`, but I suggest to avoid its use and use instead other methods).

```
WITH CAL_TAB AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ) AS DAT
         , 1 AS COUN
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1- CASE DATENAME (WEEKDAY, DATEADD(dd,-1,B.DAT) ) WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 2 WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, B.DAT ) AS DAT
         , B.COUN+1 AS COUN
    FROM CAL_TAB B 
    WHERE B.COUN<12 /* 12 is just to limit number of days */
 )
SELECT DAT, WD
FROM (SELECT C.DAT, C.COUN, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, C.DAT) AS WD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUN) AS RN
      FROM CAL_TAB C
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT DAT FROM HOL_TAB D WHERE D.DAT=C.DAT)
      ) E WHERE RN<=5;
```

Output:

```
    DAT                 WD
1   10.01.2018 00:00:00 Wednesday
2   09.01.2018 00:00:00 Tuesday
3   08.01.2018 00:00:00 Monday
4   03.01.2018 00:00:00 Wednesday
5   02.01.2018 00:00:00 Tuesday
```

Comment: Thank you very much @etsa exactly what i was required

Comment: Great job. And I don't discourage your effort. I have a small doubt. If we try this from a holiday or Saturday/Sunday, that also comes in the list. Is it ok @VickyS?

Answer (score 0):

try This Logic

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        MyDate = DATEADD(DD,-5,GETDATE())
)
SELECT
    MyDate = CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, MyDate) IN ('Sunday','Saturday')
                THEN NULL
        WHEN MHL.Holiday IS NOT NULL    
                THEN NULL
        ELSE CTE.MyDate END
    FROM CTE
        LEFT JOIN MyHoliDayList MHL
            ON CTE.MyDate = MHL.Holiday
```

Comment: It also gives me incorrect result when it shows 2018-01-05 doesn't exclude saturday sunday and holiday as well, simply removes 5 days from current date and shows as 2018-01-05

Answer (score 0):

Try this Method:

```
DECLARE @Holiday TABLE(HoliDay DATE)
INSERT INTO @Holiday VALUES ('2018-01-02')
INSERT INTO @Holiday VALUES ('2018-01-05')

DECLARE @WithOutHoliDay DATETIME = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                                    WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                                    WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3
                                    ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 5, GETDATE())))

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,0-
    (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM @Holiday 
    WHERE HoliDay BETWEEN @WithOutHoliDay AND GETDATE()),@WithOutHoliDay)
```

This should give, what exactly you need...

Comment: Thank you but it fails when i add 
INSERT INTO Holiday VALUES ('2018-01-02')
INSERT INTO Holiday VALUES ('2018-01-05')
INSERT INTO Holiday VALUES ('2018-01-04') to holiday table, returns 02-01-2018 which has to be 01-01-2018